# How to write wrapper to TransactionScope

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Hi I'm using TransactionScope on several places in my app. Like:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
        ToDo1();
        ToDo2();
        scope.Complete();
}
```

I would like to have a possibility to disable all my TransactionScopes in one place.

I imagining something like MyTransactionScope class, where I can define if I want to use it or not.

Can you give me a hint how to achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by disable the transaction scope?  Do you mean you have a statement within the scope of a transaction that you don't want to have participate in the transaction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done this. You can't inherit `TransactionScope` because it is sealed. Instead you contain the class inside your `MyTransactionScope` class. Also implement `IDisposable` so you can call it under using construct. And expose `.Complete()` and other related methods. These methods will internally call the inner contained object.

```
public sealed class MyTransactionScope : IDisposable
{
    TransactionScope _transactionScope = null;

    #region Overloaded Constructors
    public MyTransactionScope()
    {
        _transactionScope = new TransactionScope();
    }

    public MyTransactionScope(Transaction transactionToUse)
    {
        _transactionScope = new TransactionScope(transactionToUse);
    }
    #endregion

    public void Complete()
    {
        _transactionScope.Complete();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _transactionScope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - He didn't clarify what exactly he meant, but I suspect this may have been what he wanted.

Comment: @EricPetroelje yeah I've been in this boat. The need arises to have a single place to make transactionscope as NOP operation. (do nothing)

Comment: was just there on a recent project where they had multiple databases and couldn't get DTC working in their dev environment.  Had I known ahead of time that might have been an issue, building a class like this would have made things much easier.

Comment: @Lindsay To use this, replace `TransactionScope` with `MyTransactionScope` where you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean what I think you mean, then you should be able to use the `Suppress` transaction scope option:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
        using(TransactionScope scope2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)) {
           ToDo1();
           scope2.Complete();
        }

        // If ToDo2 throws an exception and the transaction is rolled back,
        // ToDo1 will still be committed since it did not participate in the
        // original (ambient) transaction.
        ToDo2();       
        scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: @Ankush below express exactly what I was mean.